# java - Stream collect toMap - Type mismatch

Tags: java, list, dictionary, stream, collectors

I am trying to collect a List of Collections into a Map, where the key is the index from the original list and the value is the collection. I tried the following, but I get a Type mismatch error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<Integer,Collection<String>>`

My code:

```
public Map<Integer, Collection<String>> myFunction(final List<Collection<String>> strs) {
    return strs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(List::indexOf, v -> v)); // Error here
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a compilation error: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method indexOf(Object) from the type List`.

If you correct it as below, it will compile:

```
return strs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(coll -> strs.indexOf(coll), v -> v));
```

Or, using a method reference:

```
return strs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(strs::indexOf, v -> v));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```java
List<Collection<Integer>> list = ...;
Map<Integer, Collection<Integer>> collect = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> list.get(v)));
```